# Whats wrong with my css code

Tags: css, responsive-design

I need some help with my css code. The color of my col is not showing up. When i remove a certain line it works.

```
@-ms-viewport{
width: device-width;
#result { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
#result .error { padding: 4px; background: #ffebe8; border: 1px #eb8a71 solid; }
#result .message { padding: 4px; background: #e8ffec; border: 1px #79ef9d solid; }

#result #grid { width: 50%; margin: 10px 0 0; }
#result #grid .even { background-color: #fff; }
#result #grid .odd { background-color: #F0F0F6; }
#result #grid .highlight { background-color: #3D3D3D; font-weight: bold; }
#result #grid .header { background: url(../images/small.gif) no-repeat #E6EEEE right center; cursor: pointer; padding: 4px; }
#result #grid .headerSortUp { background: url(../images/small_asc.gif) no-repeat #8DBDD8 right center; }
#result #grid .headerSortDown { background: url(../images/small_desc.gif) no-repeat #8DBDD8 right center; }
#result #grid .col1, #grid .col2, #grid .col3 {  }
#result #grid .col1 { width: 15%; }
#result #grid .col2 { width: 20%; }
#result #grid .col3 { width: 10%; }
#result #grid .col1 img { display: block; padding: 4px; margin: 4px 0; border: 1px #efefef solid; }
}
```

When i remove this line:

```
@-ms-viewport{
width: device-width;
```

It works but then the site isn't responsive. Can anyone help me out with this problem. I reallly need to solve this.

Comment: Please check this link:http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are defining the viewport for Microsoft Internet Explorer and you are testing on other browsers i.e. chrome/firefox/mozilla.

If that's the case, just add the necessary viewports as well:

```
@-webkit-viewport
@-moz-viewport
@-o-viewport
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use the ms viewport tag with media queries according to Microsoft:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
@media [media query logic here] {
  @-ms-viewport {
    [viewport properties here]
  }
  [CSS for this layout combination here]
}
```

So you need to close the viewport rule, which only accepts the width and then have all of your other rules.

```
@media [media query logic here] {
  @-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
  }
  #result { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
  #result .error { padding: 4px; background: #ffebe8; border: 1px #eb8a71 solid; }
  #result .message { padding: 4px; background: #e8ffec; border: 1px #79ef9d solid; }

  #result #grid { width: 50%; margin: 10px 0 0; }
  #result #grid .even { background-color: #fff; }
  #result #grid .odd { background-color: #F0F0F6; }
  #result #grid .highlight { background-color: #3D3D3D; font-weight: bold; }
  #result #grid .header { background: url(../images/small.gif) no-repeat #E6EEEE right center; cursor: pointer; padding: 4px; }
  #result #grid .headerSortUp { background: url(../images/small_asc.gif) no-repeat #8DBDD8 right center; }
  #result #grid .headerSortDown { background: url(../images/small_desc.gif) no-repeat #8DBDD8 right center; }
  #result #grid .col1, #grid .col2, #grid .col3 {  }
  #result #grid .col1 { width: 15%; }
  #result #grid .col2 { width: 20%; }
  #result #grid .col3 { width: 10%; }
  #result #grid .col1 img { display: block; padding: 4px; margin: 4px 0; border: 1px #efefef solid; }
}
```